# $\operatorname{rank}(A\circ B) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$ iff $\operatorname{Im}(B)\cap \operatorname{Ker}(A)= \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> Let $V$, $W$, $U$ be vector spaces with scalars $K$, and $B\colon V\to W$ and $A\colon W\to U$ be linear transformations.
>
> Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A\circ B) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$ if and only if $\operatorname{Im}(B)\cap \operatorname{Ker}(A)= \{0\}$

I have a problem right at the beginning: how can I show that
$\operatorname{rank}(A\circ B) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$? I think that's the clue.

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem? It might be easier to prove that the nullities are equal, since clearly, if $B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, then $A\circ B\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$, which gives one inclusion...

Comment: I know the rank-nullity theorem, but why can I use it?  This is a composition but the theorem just says something about addition. I just dont understand how to use it with composition.

Comment: You could start by applying the rank-nullity theorem to $A$, $B$ and $A\circ B$ and see what you get.

Comment: Well, $\mathrm{rank}(AB) = \dim(V) - \mathrm{nullity}(AB)$, and $\mathrm{rank}(B) = \dim(V)-\mathrm{nullity}(B)$, so to prove equality of ranks, you can try proving equality of nullities, instead...

Comment: Is $\circ$ supposed to be the Hadamard product?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof Ker(L○T) = Ker(T) $\iff$ Im(T) ∩ Ker(L) = {0}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213441/proof-kerlt-kert-iff-imt-%e2%88%a9-kerl-0)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comments : since one inclusion is quite clear from the comments I give the second inclusion.

Let $$x\in~Null(AB)\implies AB(x)=0\implies Bx \in~Null(A)$$
But also $$Bx\in Im(B)$$ But the intersection is trivial, which in turn $$\implies Bx=0\implies x\in~Null(B)$$
Hence the Null spaces are equal.

Comment: what is the first inclusion?